# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, json-deserialization

I use Spring Boot and Rappitmq so realize async messaging between two different applications. This works fine when I only exchange Strings as message content. I also imlemented the exchange of pojos. Because of the pojos beeing in different packages the serialization/deserialization process fails. To solve that  I use the JacksonConverter to use json. This works as I can see in the message header in the subscriber service "application/json"

**Model to exchange (Same in publish- and subscriber service):**

```
public class Employee{

private Integer id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Double salary;

public Employee(@JsonProperty("id") Integer id,
                @JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
                @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
                @JsonProperty("salary") Double salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(Double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", salary=" + salary +
            '}';
}
```

**Beans to use Jackson2JsonConverter in publisher service:**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class PublisherApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(PublisherApplication.class, args);

}

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerMessageConverter(){
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerMessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

}

**Send Message:**

```
    @Override
public void sendEmployeeObject(Employee employee) throws JsonProcessingException {
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitMqConstants.EXCHANGE_NAME, "foo.bar.baz", employee);
}
```

}

**Subscriber config:**

```
   @Configuration
public class EmployeeMessageSubscriberConfig {

@Bean
@Qualifier("employeeQueue")
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(RabbitMqConstants.EMPLOYEE_QUEUE, false);
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("employeeExchange")
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(RabbitMqConstants.EXCHANGE_NAME);
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("employeeQueueExchangeBinding")
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo.bar.#");
}
@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

}

**Listener Method:**

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMqConstants.EMPLOYEE_QUEUE)
    public void handleMessage(Employee employee) {

        System.out.println("Received <" + employee.toString() + ">");
    }
```

To test it I send an Employee object via rest api to the publisher service. Here I just pass it unchanged to rabbit. The subscriber service reads the message und just prints it to the console.

**The Problem:**
The subscriber service prints the correct value:

```
Received <{id=1, firstName='John', lastName='Doe', salary=1.5}>
```

but I get also an error trace:

```
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","salary":1.5}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
```

So as I understand the subscriber sees that the incoming Json is ob type Object but it tries to deserialize it as a String.

**Question:**
Why is the the correct output printed when the trace says that there seems a to be an error?
When I use a RestController, the incoming Object is mapped automatically to the given Model. Do I have to wire this up some somehow when using rabbitmq?

**EDIT:**

That's the [guide](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2016/10/23/produce-and-consume-json-messages-with-spring-boot-amqp/) I followed.

As I've seen in the header in my subscriber, there is field `headers={__TypeId__=com.publisher.model.Employee}` so I've set the Employee model in both applications to a package with the same name. Still same error. ( Like I expected because contrary to the standardMessageConverter the packe name is not used for serialization )

Comment: You should take as json as String in `handleMessage` and map jsonString to Employee inside

Comment: Are you sure? It seems one of the most common use cases to me to deserialize Json Object in Pojos. I thought it is also an advantage to use Json as it can be deserialized in other languges too without having to stick to Java specific stuff.

Comment: @medTech try by @Payload annotations ... then `handleMessage` should like this public void handleMessage(@Payload Employee message)

Comment: @DineshKrishnan nothing changed.

Comment: @medTech try `convertAndSend()` method for publishing message. So it should be `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchangeName, routingkey, messageObject);`

Comment: @DineshKrishnan sorry I forgot to print this. I already use this in a service method im my publisher application with the Rabbittemplte. In debug I've seen that the Jackson converter is used as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously that you can not receive message with a java bean directly.

try to use `byte[] msg` or `String msg` as argument for your `handleMessage()` method and transform it to your `Employee` bean manually.

If you want to receive your message with a java bean,a configuration helps.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<?> rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah but as I said the correct value also printed. So it seems to work in any way?

Comment: I just updated my answer.You just need a configuration

Comment: I added this bean but nothing changed. I stuck the most with why the correct value is beeing printed along with an error trace that it can't be deserialized. Do you have a source for that? I already thought it might be a problem with the @RabbitListener annotation

Comment: try to use @Payload for the employee argument